# Does deleting temporary symlinks interrupt current downloads/access to that symlink?

Tags: php, symlink

I am using symlinks generated in PHP. They are generated when someone requests a download, and I want them to expire at the end of each day.

The problem is, what if someone starts downloading a symlink 1 minute before the end of the day and then I delete the symlink while they are downloading it...

**My question is**, to your knowledge will that individual downloading the symlink, right before I delete it, still be able to "download" the file? I am not worried about "resumable download" capability.. but will it make their download stop or break in some way?

Comment: Elaborate. Your php script creates a symlink? User gets redirected to a download url? Then apache starts sending that file (say 50GB), right before a cron job deletes the symlink?

Comment: The only reason I need to do it this way is so I can avoid the "processes running" limit that some shared hosting enforce, because a PHP file that acts as a download script by itself means it is a running process right up until the download is finished - however with symbolic links, I get around this and download script ends right away since they are downloading the file directly through the symlink.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can do this.

On UNIX-like systems (including Linux), you don't delete files. You delete filenames. If you delete a file that someone else currently has open, the filename will be gone but the data will remain on disk until the file is closed.

Even more so with symlinks: if you delete a symlink the file data is still there, and any process with the file open refers to it by a file handle, not by filename.

So as long as you delete the symlink *after* your script opens the file, the download will complete without any trouble.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the webserver keeps the file open until the download is complete, which I would expect it to. this will work fine. On Linux you could even remove the *hardlink* to a file and the webserver would still be able to read from it as long as it's kept open

Answer (score 1):

My experience says otherwise.
If there is an interruption (in the connection), or if the user chooses to pause the download, the browser will not always be able to resume (because the link is gone).

I've tried IE9x Chrome23.x Firefox17.x  (on an Apache Shared Server)

What I did, was to put the symlinks in unique folders, and delete folders based on time.  In my case, I kill the folder (and it's included symlink) after 30minutes  (a reasonable time for my download files.)

(I can't take credit for this idea---saw it somewhere else)
I will say that very short interruptions or pauses can sometimes be recovered.